# Create ip range from start and end point in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have start IP address and end IP address. I want to create range between these ip address.

For example :

```
start = '10.10.1.0'
end = '10.10.10.10'
```

Output must be like.

```
10.10.1.0
10.10.1.1
10.10.1.2
...
...
10.10.1.255
10.10.2.0
10.10.2.1
...
...
10.10.10.9
10.10.10.10
```

Is there any object in JavaScript which give range from start and end IP address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at IP addresses in hex is really useful here.  Each number between the periods is called two "octet" which means grouping of 16 bits.  The maximum value of each number is 255, or 0xFF in hex.  Your starting address of **10.10.1.0** is represented as **0x0A0A0100** in hex.  Your ending address is **0x0A0A0A0A**.

I've written a JSFiddle to show you how simple it is to count through IP addresses once you represent them in hex.

http://jsfiddle.net/sL7VM/

Here is the most important part of the code:

```
for(var i = 0x0A0A0100; i < 0x0A0A0A0A; i++)
{   
    var oc4 = (i>>24) & 0xff;
    var oc3 = (i>>16) & 0xff;
    var oc2 = (i>>8) & 0xff;
    var oc1 = i & 0xff;

    $('#output').append(oc4 + "." + oc3 + "." + oc2 + "." + oc1 + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: How can I convert "10.10.1.0" (String) to 0x0A0A0100 (Hex) ?

Comment: Split the string on ".".  Then multiply the first one by 1, the next one by 256, the next by 65536, and the last by 16777216.  Add all four numbers together.  The multipliers I've listed are in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this in native javascript other than splitting the start and end on the "." char and then creating a loop. It may be achievable by a library.

Have you had a look at this one? https://code.google.com/p/iplib-js/